# How to get PassedTestCount and FailedTestCount in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm making a request to `guestAuth/app/rest/builds/id:2777/statistics` as defined here, http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-OtherBuildRequests. If I understand the documentation correctly it is supposed to list the parameters defined here, http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Custom+Chart#CustomChart-listOfDefaultStatisticValues, but I can't find the `PassedTestCount` and `FailedTestCount`.

Is there another way to get those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the way TeamCity works is if the Tests that are run are supported they will show up under the `Tests` tab for a build, then you will be able to see those in two places in the REST API.

First under `/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/id:X` where X is the Build ID Number. What you will see is a `<statusText>` tag which will contain text like:

```
<statusText>Tests passed: 4</statusText>
<statusText>Tests failed: 2 (2 new), passed: 6</statusText>
<statusText>Tests failed: 2, passed: 6</statusText>
```

That you could in theory parse out to get your numbers.

However, they are also under `/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/id:X/statistics` using the following tags:

```
<property name="FailedTestCount" value="2"/>
<property name="PassedTestCount" value="6"/>
```

However, should there be no failed tests, the "FailedTestCount" property tag won't be there.

If your tests are not showing up under the `Test`, then you can look into [TeamCity Service Messages for Build Script Interaction](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingTests) that can Report Test Start / End with Failure in the middle if found.

For example, you can create a new build with just a Command Line Custom Script build step with:

```
echo "##teamcity[testSuiteStarted name='suite.name']"
echo "##teamcity[testSuiteStarted name='nested.suite']"
echo "##teamcity[testStarted name='package_or_namespace.ClassName.TestName']"
echo "##teamcity[testFailed name='package_or_namespace.ClassName.TestName' message='The number should be 20000' details='junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<20000> but was:<10000>|n|r    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)|n|r    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:280)|n|r...']"
echo "##teamcity[testFinished name='package_or_namespace.ClassName.TestName']"
echo "##teamcity[testStarted name='package_or_namespace.ClassName.TestNameTwo']"
echo "##teamcity[testFinished name='package_or_namespace.ClassName.TestNameTwo']"
echo "##teamcity[testSuiteFinished name='nested.suite']"
echo "##teamcity[testSuiteFinished name='suite.name']"
```

And it will end up showing:

```
<property name="FailedTestCount" value="1"/>
<property name="PassedTestCount" value="1"/>
```

Under `/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/id:X/statistics` if you run the test. Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem was that I was checking against a project that didn't have the tests running... doh!

Comment: Yep. That would do it!